# Swift 3.0 Protocol instantiation

Tags: swift, swift3, protocols, instantiation

Here's my declaration of an array of command classes.

```
var commands: [IPICommand.Type] = [CLoginCommand.self]
```

`IPICommand` is a protocol and the `CLoginCommand` is a class that implements the protocol. In the array now I have only one element, but there can be more.

After this I would like to instantiate one of the elements of the array:

```
let aCommand = commands[0]()
```

Currently the instantiation has issues: Cannot call value of non-function type 'IPICommand.Type'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to instantiate a `IPICommand` type, that is a protocol.
To make it works, define an `init` method in your protocol declaration

```
protocol IPICommand {
    init()
}
```

In this way you can do `commands[0]()`.
I'd prefer to name the init in an another way, but this is up to you.

Comment: You're right. The `commands[0]()` isn't working, but `commands[0].init()` does work and it is a small difference.